# New Windows 7 git install, missing commands in bins, e.g. alias for git bash

Tags: windows, alias, git-bash

Just installed git on my Windows 7 laptop and desktop and it seems that some standard Unix commands are missing in the setup.  I'm new to Git and not that great with Windows stuff.

I found out the issue by trying to configure the git bash using a `.bashrc` by adding a simple alias thus:

```
alias ls 'ls -F'
```

When the `.bashrc` is run (and it's getting executed when the shell starts), I get this message:

```
$ alias ls 'ls -F'

bash: alias: ls: not found

bash: alias: ls -F: not found
```

Upon closer examination of the bin directories (`/bin`, `/usr/bin`, i.e. `C:\Program Files\Git\bin` and `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin`, respectively) there is no `alias` or `alias.exe`.

I'm assuming this has something to do with Unix commands re-created into windows executable and not some branch of a path that I'm missing.  I've checked on the path and cannot find some hidden bin directory.

I've seen several postings on installing Cygwin on it's own and I can do this but before launching into a protracted fix for both my laptop and desktop I'd like to know if I'm missing something or my git initial install is bad or if there's a package that I should be adding -- would appreciate any assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax would be:

```
alias ls='ls -F'
```

alias is a [bash builtin command](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html), so you won't find an alias.exe anywhere in the git distribution.